# cannot link css file to file

Tags: javascript, html, css

for some reason I my index.html does not read the style.css. It is linked though. what is the issue ?  I added the type, I did add the right path I think.
thank you

[image]

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title> </title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!--Main Start-->
<div class='main'>
<!--Home Section Start-->
 <section class='home-section'>
  <div class='container'>
   < div class ='row'>
    <div class='home-text'>
      <p> </p>
      <h1> </h1>
      <h2></h2>
    </div>
    <div class='home-img'></div>
  </div>
</div>

</section>
<!-- Home Section End-->


</div>
<!--Main End-->

<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the physical file `style.css` ??  Is it in a `css` directory?  If so it would look something like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">`

Comment: Open your files make sure the **style.css** file is in the same folder as your **index.html** page =>  `href="style.css"` indicates the file is in the same folder as the page that the code came from here in your question, if that is your **index.html** file then it will go there.

Comment: Perhaps taking a screen shot of your file directory showing the path may help.

Comment: I did put a screen. thank you

Comment: Now what makes you so sure it's not pulling in?  What does your `CSS` file look like?

Comment: i did put a screen of my css, i have a body with a background-image

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved, it was that I forgot one root variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just Try :

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome.css">
<!-- Here Head Content-->
</head>
<body>
<!-- Here Body Content-->
</body> 
<html>
```

But also after you added screenshot for your CSS File you said in previous
answer that it the problem was from the CSS File not the linking (That mean if
there is something wrong with your CSS File the whole file not work)

Answer (score -1):

One possible cause of such problems are browser cache.

If you are on windows, try running ***ctrl+f5*** to reload the page.

Answer (score -3):

Every thing is correct whith you, the only thing that may be wrong is that the css file is not in  the same folder with the index, for no reason, also try removing type="text/css",it may work.